# Adding Custom Models to Armor in Minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've recently gotten into modding Minecraft and thought that my first released mod may be something that provides wings with the functionality of those from Terraria (Hold space to fly up for a limited time after which you can't fly up until you touch the ground. At this time the wings, instead, provide a slow fall).

So far I've added the items, recipes, etc. I've decided to use and I have my first set of wings as an armour, however, as I have not set a texture they show up as the pink / black checkers. What I actually want is for there to be a different model used- the custom one I made for the wings known as `Resting.java` but change to `Flying.java` whilst in the air.

My problem here is that I don't know how to get rid of the default armour model and use my one. Also I'd like to be able to actually add functionality (the flying, gliding, etc.) which I don't know how to do but I'll save that for another question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need me to post any of my code, just say so. I don't know what would be needed.

I'm currently editing Minecraft Version 1.6.4 using the latest release of Forge.

Comment: If you have a question that involves code, you always post the relevant code. Please read the [Stack Overflow help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I understand that, however, I don't know if someone would need my main class or the class of the item or if they'd want to see the code of my model... I understand there's probably spoiler tags to cut down on size but I think posting three files of code might be a bit of a clunky solution.

Comment: You'll probably have more success asking this on the [Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/).

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. This was my first port-of-call as I wasn't really sure of where to ask it but I've gotten good solutions to things on here before.

Comment: This is a website for people that got stuck during program. You can always ask for algorithm (and similar) problems on here even for Minecraft mods but I agree with Chris. You might always get more success on the Forge forums.

Answer (score 1):

this was asked a while ago, but there is a way to do it. Use custom model data to make custom elyta or chestplates, and then put effects such as jump boost and slowfalling on people with the custom wings in their chest slot in armor. I know this was asked a while ago but I hate that nobody answered these questions. Yay!